# how to determine from inside of function if variable passed to it was by reference or not?

Tags: php, php-5.3

```
function do_sth_with_var($variable) {
  if (is_by_reference($variable)) {
    $variable = something($variable)
  }
  else {
    return something($variable);
  }
}
```

so for example if 'something' was strtoupper:

```
do_sth_with_var(&$str); // would make $str uppercase, but
$str = do_sth_with_var($str); // that way should it be done if ommitting that '&'
```

Comment: Okay, amuse me. *Why* would the person writing the function not know whether or not it was passed by reference...

Comment: As long as you know what your doing (read all the answers below), this question is legitimate.

Answer (score 3):

*Disclaimer: This does not directly answer the OP's question, but I'm providing this answer in the hope that it will help him/her.*

I'd say, provide a **consistent interface**. Declare the function parameter as reference:

```
function do_sth_with_var(&$variable) {
```

and it will always be a reference.

You could also to the contrary and always copy the value:

```
function do_sth_with_var($variable) {
    $val = $variable;
    // work with $val here
    return $val;
}
```

No built-in PHP function I know changes its behaviour based on whether you pass a reference or not. They are clearly defined to either treat an argument as reference or not and I would argue that users are used to this clear definitions and can deal with them.

For example, `sort` always sorts an array in place. You know that. So if you want to keep the original, you make a copy before the call.

It depends on your function whether it makes sense to perform an in-place operation or not. E.g. it makes sense for `sort` but I'd say it does not make sense for string processing.

Also, as you are using PHP 5.3, [passing variables by reference at call-time is deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php):

> As of PHP 5.3.0, you will get a warning saying that "call-time pass-by-reference" is deprecated when you use `&` in `foo(&$a);`.

So you (or whoever) should not do that anyway.

Comment: Yes but it would be nice from the user point of this function to determine it's behavior by passing variable to it as reference or not, passing by reference means that is ok for me to function replacing that variable with sth else.

Comment: @user393087: As said, passing a variable as reference like you should in your example is deprecated. Why would you want to consider it? There is no buillt-in PHP function that distinguishes between reference or not. They either return always a value, or always a reference. Be consistent, that is the most important thing.

Comment: in real world it makes sense to ask those questions. and in real world people sometimes have to deal with deprecated code. -> (-1)

Comment: @Raffael1984: And why do you think my answer is not useful? You say it is just not possible but you don't give any advice about how to deal with such a situation... does not seem to be more useful to me. Especially if there is no way to determine that, defining a function like that will always give you a reference and you don't have to worry about whether someone passes the value as reference or not.

Comment: yes I do ... right below your answer. and your answer isn't useless. though I hate those wise answers myself. it distracts from the core of the question. sometimes it's not all about best practices, but about how thinks actually work.

Comment: @Raffael1984: Then I don't understand why you give a -1. -1 means *this answer is not useful*. But hey, you can do whatever you want ;)

Comment: your answer is not useful ... it is not answering the question ... :-)

Comment: @Raffael1984: True :) But I hope it helps the OP anyway. Literally answering a question does not always help ;)

Answer (score 1):

calltime-pass-by-ref is considered deprecated as of 5.3.

apart from that ... answering the question academically; I don't think there is any way to determine that propperly, b/c there is no difference between a "reference" and a usual parameter. In PHP every variable is a pointer to section in the symbol table. A reference just makes another variable point to the same section.

in PHP there are no references as C knows them for example. every variable is a pointer and every "reference" too.

PS: @Gordon: I forgot about the Reflection-Classes. Of course, they work on a meta-level. My answer is more directed at how PHP actually deals with paramters and variables.

Answer (score 0):

This topic is covered very well by the first comment [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.spot.php) (official php manual)

Answer (score 0):

to answer your question literally, you can try experimenting with [debug_zval_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-zval-dump.php). Refcounts will be different for by val and by reference parameters.

```
function xxx($a) {
    debug_zval_dump($a);
}

$b = 123;
xxx($b);   // long(123) refcount(4)
xxx(&$b);  // long(123) refcount(1)
```

Comment: I was thinking about that function, too, but how reliable is that?

Answer (score -1):

In your specific case you don't need to know if the value is passed by reference or not you can do something like:

```
function do_sth_with_var($variable) {
  $variable = something($variable)
  return $variable;
}
```

It should do exactly what you ask in your question

I don't know any good and safe way to control that a passed parameter is a reference and not just a value inside the body of a function at running time.

Comment: @user393087 even down voted I can assure you that my answer respond to your need, just give it a try. But as stated in other comments, don't forget the deprecation of call-time pass-by-reference in php 5.3